# Terraform wants to delete a bucket, and complains it is not empty. I don't want terraform to delete the bucket. How do I tell it not to?

Tags: terraform

I have terraform that is producing the following log on apply:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket" {
        action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        function_name = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<secret>:function:ProggyS3ObjectCreatedHandler"
      ~ id            = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket" -> (known after apply)
        principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      ~ source_arn    = "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-example-us-east-1" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
        statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
    }

  # aws_s3_bucket.bucket must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
      + acceleration_status         = (known after apply)
        acl                         = "private"
      ~ arn                         = "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-example-us-east-1" -> (known after apply)
      ~ bucket                      = "bucket-example-us-east-1" -> "sftp-assembly-us-east-1" # forces replacement
      ~ bucket_domain_name          = "bucket-example-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
      ~ bucket_regional_domain_name = "bucket-example-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
        force_destroy               = false
      ~ hosted_zone_id              = "FOOBAR" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                          = "bucket-example-us-east-1" -> (known after apply)
      ~ region                      = "us-east-1" -> (known after apply)
      ~ request_payer               = "BucketOwner" -> (known after apply)
      ~ tags                        = {
          ~ "Name" = "bucket-example-us-east-1" -> "sftp-assembly-us-east-1"
        }
      + website_domain              = (known after apply)
      + website_endpoint            = (known after apply)

        versioning {
            enabled    = false
            mfa_delete = false
        }
    }

  # aws_s3_bucket_notification.bucket_notification must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
      ~ bucket = "bucket-example-us-east-1" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
      ~ id     = "bucket-example-us-east-1" -> (known after apply)

      ~ lambda_function {
            events              = [
                "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
            ]
          ~ id                  = "tf-s3-lambda-FOOBAR" -> (known after apply)
            lambda_function_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<secret>:function:ProggyS3ObjectCreatedHandler"
        }
    }

  # module.large-file-breaker-lambda-primary.aws_lambda_function.lambda will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
        arn                            = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<secret>:function:ProggyLargeFileBreaker"
        function_name                  = "ProggyLargeFileBreaker"
        handler                        = "break-large-files"
        id                             = "ProggyLargeFileBreaker"
        invoke_arn                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<secret>:function:ProggyLargeFileBreaker/invocations"
        last_modified                  = "2020-03-13T20:17:33.376+0000"
        layers                         = []
        memory_size                    = 3008
        publish                        = false
        qualified_arn                  = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<secret>:function:ProggyLargeFileBreaker:$LATEST"
        reserved_concurrent_executions = -1
        role                           = "arn:aws:iam::<secret>:role/ProggyLargeFileBreaker-role20200310215329691700000001"
        runtime                        = "go1.x"
        s3_bucket                      = "repo-us-east-1"
        s3_key                         = "Proggy-large-file-breaker/1.0.10/break-large-files-1.0.10.zip"
        source_code_hash               = "TbwleLcqD+xL2zOYk6ZdiBWAAznCIiTS/6nzrWqYZhE="
        source_code_size               = 7294687
      ~ tags                           = {
            "Name"          = "ProggyLargeFileBreaker"
          ~ "TerraformRepo" = "https://git.com/wwexdevelopment/aws-terraform-projects/commits/tag/v2.0.11" -> "https://git.com/wwexdevelopment/aws-terraform-projects/commits/tag/v2.0.16"
            "Version"       = "1.0.10"
            "account"       = "main"
            "environment"   = "assembly"
            "source"        = "terraform"
            "type"          = "ops"
        }
        timeout                        = 360
        version                        = "$LATEST"

        environment {
            variables = {
                "ARCHIVE_BUCKET"       = "Proggy-archive-assembly-us-east-1"
                "S3_OBJECT_SIZE_LIMIT" = "15000000"
            }
        }

        tracing_config {
            mode = "PassThrough"
        }
    }

  # module.notifier-lambda-primary.aws_lambda_function.lambda will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
        arn                            = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<secret>:function:ProggyS3ObjectCreatedHandler"
        function_name                  = "ProggyS3ObjectCreatedHandler"
        handler                        = "s3-Proggy-notifier"
        id                             = "ProggyS3ObjectCreatedHandler"
        invoke_arn                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<secret>:function:ProggyS3ObjectCreatedHandler/invocations"
        last_modified                  = "2020-03-11T20:52:33.256+0000"
        layers                         = []
        memory_size                    = 128
        publish                        = false
        qualified_arn                  = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<secret>:function:ProggyS3ObjectCreatedHandler:$LATEST"
        reserved_concurrent_executions = -1
        role                           = "arn:aws:iam::<secret>:role/ProggyS3ObjectCreatedHandler-role20200310215329780600000001"
        runtime                        = "go1.x"
        s3_bucket                      = "repo-us-east-1"
        s3_key                         = "s3-Proggy-notifier/1.0.55/s3-Proggy-notifier-1.0.55.zip"
        source_code_hash               = "4N+B1GpaUY/wB4S7tR1eWRnNuHnBExcEzmO+mqhQ5B4="
        source_code_size               = 6787828
      ~ tags                           = {
            "Name"          = "ProggyS3ObjectCreatedHandler"
          ~ "TerraformRepo" = "https://git.com/wwexdevelopment/aws-terraform-projects/commits/tag/v2.0.11" -> "https://git.com/wwexdevelopment/aws-terraform-projects/commits/tag/v2.0.16"
            "Version"       = "1.0.55"
            "account"       = "main"
            "environment"   = "assembly"
            "source"        = "terraform"
            "type"          = "ops"
        }
        timeout                        = 360
        version                        = "$LATEST"

        environment {
            variables = {
                "FILE_BREAKER_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME" = "ProggyLargeFileBreaker"
                "Proggy_SQS_QUEUE_NAME"              = "Proggy_Proggy_edi-notification.fifo"
                "Proggy_SQS_QUEUE_URL"               = "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<secret>/Proggy_Proggy_edi-notification.fifo"
                "S3_OBJECT_SIZE_LIMIT"              = "15000000"
            }
        }

        tracing_config {
            mode = "PassThrough"
        }
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 2 to change, 3 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

module.large-file-breaker-lambda-primary.aws_lambda_function.lambda: Modifying... [id=ProggyLargeFileBreaker]
module.notifier-lambda-primary.aws_lambda_function.lambda: Modifying... [id=ProggyS3ObjectCreatedHandler]
aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket: Destroying... [id=AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket]
aws_s3_bucket_notification.bucket_notification: Destroying... [id=bucket-example-us-east-1]
module.large-file-breaker-lambda-primary.aws_lambda_function.lambda: Modifications complete after 0s [id=ProggyLargeFileBreaker]
aws_s3_bucket_notification.bucket_notification: Destruction complete after 0s
aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket: Destruction complete after 0s
aws_s3_bucket.bucket: Destroying... [id=bucket-example-us-east-1]
module.notifier-lambda-primary.aws_lambda_function.lambda: Modifications complete after 0s [id=ProggyS3ObjectCreatedHandler]

Error: error deleting S3 Bucket (bucket-example-us-east-1): BucketNotEmpty: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket.
    status code: 409, request id: 0916517C5F1DF875, host id: +l5yzHjw7EMmdT4xdCmgg0Zx5W7zxpEil/dUWeJmnL8IvfPw2uKgvJ2Ee7utlRI0rkohdY+pjYI=
```

It wants to delete that bucket because I formerly told it to create it (I think).  But I don't want terraform to delete that bucket.  The bucket it's trying to delete is in use by other teams.

How can I tell terraform to do the apply, but not delete that bucket?

Comment: Don't change the name of it. You can't modify the name of a bucket so if you tell Terraform to do it then it will create a plan to destroy it and then replace it with the new name.

Comment: Is there no way to tell terraform to add the new bucket, but not delete the old one?  I can see what you mean, this is saying "take bucketA and change it to have the name bucketB" which means replacement.  But, ok how can I tell terraform to create an entirely new bucket.  Does it assume I mean replacement because of the  resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" line?  Like, if I changed it to resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket1", would it create a new bucket and leave the old one in place?

Comment: Create a new S3 bucket resource alongside. You should go and read about how Terraform works and what the state means before you go too much further along here.

Answer (score 3):

Put prevent_destroy in the S3 bucket resource to make sure it will not be deleted by any chance.

```
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
```

Remove all resource definitions from .tf files other than the S3 bucket. Run terraform plan to see if Terraform will destroy other than the S3 bucket.

If it shows expected, then run terraform apply.

Then recreate resources you need besides the S3 bucket, but those resource being placed in different place, so that the S3 bucket will be left out.

Or, use terraform rm to remove other resources from the state file other than the S3 bucket. Then run terraform import to import them into new tf files in other location.

Answer (score 1):

> ~ bucket = "bucket-example-us-east-1" -> "sftp-assembly-us-east-1" # forces replacement

You can see the annotation from terraform at the end of this line tells you that changing the bucket name forces the resource to be replaced(deleted and created).

If this is a separate bucket you need to create a new terraform resource for it, call it `bucket1` or whatever:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket1" {
  ...
}
```

If the bucket is now empty it may be easier to just delete the bucket and have terraform create it for you, that way you don't have to mess with the import commands. If bucket already exists and contains files you will need to import the resource into the state file. This will help you on how to import:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html

Answer (score -3):

The change in the tag value is forcing a new `-/+ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket"`

```
      ~ tags                        = {
          ~ "Name" = "bucket-example-us-east-1" -> "sftp-assembly-us-east-1"
        }
```

You can use [Lifecycle - ignore_changes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#ignore_changes) meta-argument to ignore tag value changes forcing a new resource.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
    # ...

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags["Name"],
    ]
  }
}
```

After adding tags in the `ignore_changes` meta argument if you find other change in values of any other parameter forcing a new bucket then you can also include them in `ignore_changes`

You can also remove this resource from the state file using the command `terraform state rm aws_s3_bucket.bucket`. This will allow you to create a new bucket without deleting the old one. Since the S3 bucket names are universally unique so you need to give new bucket name.

Another option is, after deleting the resource from the state file, [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html) it using the command `terraform import aws_s3_bucket.bucket <bucket name>`

Comment: No. It's the actual bucket name that's causing the issue. Tags are mutable, bucket names aren't.

Comment: in that case, you can remove this resource from the state file and give a new name to the bucket. This will allow you to create a new bucket without deleting the old one. I have mentioned the command in the above answer

Comment: Why are you then telling them to remove it from the state and then import it back in? What does that achieve?

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly then at the moment, the new resource is forced because of the mismatch in the bucket name the terraform code and the one present in the state file. If you don't want to recreate bucket because of its name change then reimporting the bucket after removing it from state file will refresh the bucket name in the state file and it will not force it's recreation.

Comment: If you don't want to maintain this bucket through terraform then just remove it from state file and terraform code.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - The suggestion to remove it from the state file is given in the second answer as well.